# Cesium handle viewer animation playing/pause

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

There is a few ways that i see to handle playing/pause animation in Cesium.
First - is to bind event listeners to all buttons that could start/stop animation, like this:

```
let ctrls = document.getElementsByClassName("CONTROLS_THAT_COULD_CHANGE_ANIMATING_STATE");
Array.from(classname).forEach(function(ctrls) {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /* handle change animating state */
  });
});
```

But I think it is a little brutal.

Another way is to use cesium clock and its onTick event

```
viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener((clock) => {
  console.log(clock._shouldAnimate);
});
```

This decision would be good if not lodash in the attribute title, which says that the developers of cesium let us know, not to use this.

So, Im interested what is really proper way to handle animation playing/pause in Cesium.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the `Clock`, Cesium Viewer also maintains a `ClockViewModel`, which is the UI binding for the clock.  `ClockViewModel` has a Boolean property called `shouldAnimate` that indicates whether the clock is currently animating.  The [documentation for `shouldAnimate`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ClockViewModel.html#shouldAnimate) has a little note at the end that says:

> This property is observable.

Internally, Cesium is using Knockout observables to bind view models to the UI.  So we need to go get that observable, and observe it.

[Live Demo - Sandcastle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=jVBLa8MwDP4rJpekUBx2Xho2et3oYbCTL46jpiKKXSw7pRv973OSFboHYzpZ30uSR+3FiHACLzbCwklsgTEO8nXGitzM7dbZoNGCz1f3yir7KeqtM72LQXYQdg2DH3VDUCx50lBip5xn1wKtlRV/Vs4HF6l9tDjoAPlKcmzYeGyg2EdrAjpbIC802m4l3pdE3Itf8amMs+wIJLmuyJelxbyWQBb6apHzVZP+IoAY/p1w1JGhvbEre5ne2TqrOJwJ6gV/wOHofBDRUyFlGWA4UrqRyyaaHoI0zJOtKq+mqsVRYLtR2bf/V1marpkTs49EL/gGKqurMum/2MjpNl22G8GTPk+Sw139tIBSyqpM7U9XcI4a7W8SPwA)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

Cesium.knockout.getObservable(viewer.clockViewModel,
                              'shouldAnimate').subscribe(function(isAnimating) {
    if (isAnimating) {
        console.log('Cesium clock is animating.');
    } else {
        console.log('Cesium clock is paused.');
    }
});
```

In addition to this, you can add your own play/pause controls of any type, that write a Boolean value to `shouldAnimate`, like this:

```
function onMyCustomPlayButtonClicked() {
    viewer.clockViewModel.shouldAnimate = true;
}
```

When doing this, your own play/pause controls will do more than just control the play/pause state, they will affect the visual highlights of the original play/pause controls as well, because those controls are also listening to the observable.  Thanks to Knockout, the subscription only fires when the state actually changes, so a user repeatedly clicking the play button will not generate multiple callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, emackey. Really confusing why shouldAnimate could not be get from onTick(clock).

Comment: Partly for legacy reasons, partly for performance.  `Clock` is a lightweight object that can handle being called at 60fps and higher with minimal memory footprint.  `ClockViewModel` is a heavier object, with Knockout bindings, that is meant to be interacted with on user events and such but not be called 60+ times per second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still works... I'm wondering though: how would one, without too much difficulty, figure this kind of thing out for themselves? It's not documented AFAIK...